# Dealing with a coworker who is spreading rumors to customers

Tags: professionalism, communication, clients

I have a coworker (Jane) who works for the same, medium-sized organization I do. Jane and I have known each other for quite some time, though we were never more than acquaintances, our last interaction several months ago was pleasant.

I work for the daycare in our organization, which is available both to employees and the general public. Jane works in an unrelated department. Today, it came to my attention that Jane has been spreading rumors about me not only within the organization, but also to parents of the children I watch (some internal employees, some general public). I've noticed some of the parents treating me differently, though I don't know what the rumor is.

I also applied for an internal job; Jane apparently spoke to the hiring manager, absent either my request or hers, and said I would not be a good fit, though I suspect far less politely.

Feeling hurt, frustrated, and betrayed, my first instinct was to go to HR, though it occurred to me that this can quickly devolve into a "he-said-she-said". My other thought was to confront the some of the parents who have been treating me differently to see why Jane has said about me. While I have not asked my manager about this, I suspect this sort of interaction would be out-of-bounds, and so have not followed through.

What can I do to counter this problem so that I can progress in my career with the company and improve my relationship with my clients (the parents of the children I watch)?

Comment: Now *this* is HR territory.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: You know she is spreading rumors but you don't know the rumor.   Just how to you know she is spreading rumors?

Comment: We can not tell you what to do.  If you have an idea of what goal you want to achieve from this point we can help.  I have edited the question to ask what I think you want to know.  Feel free to [edit] the question if I got it wrong.

Comment: @chad, I thought the original question was plain: "how can I make things return to normal?" Advancing my career is not necessarily a long term goal, creating a comfortable work environment and maintaining strong trust relationships is. I will leave the edit for now to see if it generates responses from other perspectives.

Comment: @Paparazzi, this information came from a coworker whom I trust implicitly

Comment: But the coworker whom you trust  implicitly will not tell you the rumor?

Comment: @agentroadkill - I kind of described what normal would be in workplace terms to prevent the question from being closed.  Normal is a very subjective term.  This kind of spelled out what normal would be based on the problems listed in the question (promotion blocked, coworkers treating you differently)

Comment: @Paparazzi I am not sure that they know the rumor

Answer (score 5):

I am not in HR, but I am sure "you" should immediately go to HR and explain the situation.  This woman is hurting your reputation and the companies by spreading negative information.  HR should investigate and talk with her and the parents to see what is going on and take appropriate action.  It is not her place to spread negative information even if it was true.

Comment: What will help you with HR is that the woman is hurting _the company's_ reputation with customers.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a parent that you have been friendly with, go to them and explain that you suspect that someone is speaking badly about you and ask them if they have heard anything.  What you do not want to do is make a big deal out of it.

I would also speak to the manager for the position you applied for.  I would not mention Jane and what she may have/did totally say, but instead approach it as what can I do to be better suited for this job in the future.  That answer may give you a idea of what he was told.